# Load more button doesn't functioned on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm learning wordpress on the fly while building a site. Now I'm trying to put 'Load More' button under the posts and when I click on it to load next portion of the posts.

I've followed one tutorial which I found. What I've added to the `function.php` is

```
function my_load_more_scripts() {

    global $wp_query; 

    wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/myloadmore.js', array('jquery') );

    wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'loadmore_params', array(
        'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // WordPress AJAX
        'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), // everything about your loop is here
        'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_more_scripts' );

function loadmore_ajax_handler(){

    $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';

    query_posts( $args );

    if( have_posts() ) :

        // run the loop
        while( have_posts() ): the_post();   
             the_title();
        endwhile;

    endif;
    die;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_{action}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
```

This is the javascript part

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.loadmore').click(function(){

        var button = $(this),
            data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': loadmore_params.posts, 
            'page' : loadmore_params.current_page
        };

        $.ajax({ // you can also use $.post here
            url : loadmore_params.ajaxurl, // AJAX handler
            data : data,
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                button.text('Loading...'); 
            },
            success : function( data ){
                if( data ) { 
                    button.text( 'More posts' ).prev().before(data); // insert new posts
                    loadmore_params.current_page++;

                    if ( loadmore_params.current_page == loadmore_params.max_page ) 
                        button.remove();

                } else {
                    button.remove();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this is the button

```
    <?php

        $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'category_name' => 'jobs', // this is the category SLUG
        ));
     ?>
     <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
         <?php the_title(); ?>
     <?php endwhile; ?>

<span class="loadmore">More posts</span>
```

I have 2 posts in the category `Jobs(slug = jobs)` also as you can see above I have added posts_per_page to be 1 in order to test the button.

I see one post on the page and the button bellow but when I click on `More posts` instead of loading one more post it just show `0` on the page, above the current visible post.

This is the custom page template, not the index.php if it's matter.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: you can add read more function with just css and little JS

Comment: @Vishwa, can you show me an example?

Comment: you can try this one if it's a match for your requirement [here](https://github.com/vishvega/Inline-Read_More-Read_Less-button)

Comment: I'm not sure if this gonna work "with just css",. It steel need some function for taking the posts I believe?

Comment: you can load wordpress posts using standard methods, I provide that solution assuming you've successfully done that. and that solution is not just css

Comment: Let me try it and will let you know. But still not sure how to make this for posts, since I see that this shortening texts..